# Adding onLeave on fullpage.js breaks scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I am using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo) and it is a fantastic plugin, however, after I add onLeave callback to the page (default sample from the github), the fancy scroll functionality i.e. instead of scrolling one section up or down per mouse scroll regardless of the scrolling length, it jumps one section per scroll step.

I was told in the fullpage.js issues section that the issue has been solved and that I should use the most update library but I have tried both the CDN as well as installing the plug into my project and the problem still persists.

I apologize that I am unable to include an example of the problem - I could not reproduce it in jsfiddle.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your project on public? or local?

Comment: I apologize for wasting your time, I resolved the issue, I did not realise that both afterload and onLeave were supposed to be put into the same $('#fullpage').fullpage({}) and separated by a coma

Comment: I apologize for wasting your time, I have been doing it wrong i.e. I had made two separate $('#fullpage').fullpage({}) for afterLoad and onLeave, but when I put them in one and separate by a coma they work.

Thank you and sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it i.e. I was doing it wrong before - I had created a new $('#fullpage').fullpage({}) for afterLoad and onLeave.

When I put them in the same and separate them by a coma they are working as intended.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
            var loadedSection = $(this);

            //using index
            if(index == 3){
                //alert("Section 3 ended loading");
            }

            //using anchorLink
            if(anchorLink == 'secondSlide'){
                //alert("Section 2 ended loading");
            }
        },

        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
            var leavingSection = $(this);

            //after leaving section 2
            if(index == 2 && direction =='down'){
                alert("Going to section 3!");
            }

            else if(index == 2 && direction == 'up'){
                //alert("Going to section 1!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Sorry for having wasted your time and again props to the creator for the nice plugin :)